# Add the key of a duplicated value to a list python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of students like `dic={1:[1,2],2:[1],3:[1,4]}`. I need to sort it, and see if the students have the same values. If that happens, the student that comes up first has priority and the other student has 2 options. For example, in the example above, nothing happens to student 1, student 2 should be added to a separate list since the value 1 has already been used, and student 3 since it has a value that hasn't appeared before, nothing happens to it too. So basicly the output I would need for that example would be `[2]`.
I managed to sort the dictionary by doing `sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])` but I don't know how to compare them, the only thing I know is that after the comparison I would have to do something like

```
list=[]
list.append(number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a set to cumulatively keep the previous values, and iterate your dictionary.

Code could be:

```
prev = set()                       # no values initialy seen
new_list = []                      # no student intialy in the new liest
for st, vals in dic.items():       # iterate on dic
    if set(vals).issubset(prev):   # is there no new value?
        new_list.append(st)        # add the student to new_list
    prev = prev.union(set(vals))   # and add its values to the seen set
```

With your example, we get as expected `[2]` for `new_list`.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to iterate the dictionary, but I understand it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For each element you can check whether it is a subset of any previous values with O(n2) complexity

```py
dic={1:[1,2],2:[1],3:[1,4]}

st_values = list(dic.values())
keys = list(dic.keys())
output = []
for i,v in enumerate(st_values):
    for j in range(0, i):
        if(set(v).issubset(st_values[j])):
            output.append(keys[i])
            
print(output)
```

```
[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets. Since the sorted() function you used returns a list of tuples:

```
dic = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])
appeared=set()
t=[]
for item in dic:
    if not set(item[1]).issubset(appeared):
        appeared.update(item[1])
    else:
        t.append(item[0])
print(f'Result: {t}')
```

Output:

```
Result: [2]
```